# how to get the the data instantly after inserting in database in php?

Tags: php

I am creating a website audit tool now in this someone will insert details of their website and answer some questions and i am inserting that in the database. Now I want to show results in new page according to the choices user makes now how can I get the details of that inserted data instantly any way to get that through PHP?

Comment: Welcome. Stack Overflow is *"a little bit different from other sites"*; to get the best out of it, please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [how to ask an On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - as it stands, this question is far too broad for SO's basic QA format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the same way you would normally get data. When loading the new page, have your controller load the data and then include it.

If this is asynchronous or doesn't include a page refresh, then you could handle this more quickly with JavaScript.